# Assigning group membership to users from Mysql database using PHP

Tags: php, mysql

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5s36k.png)

```
Users table

Id username  firstname  lastname
1  pmartin   Paul   Martin
2  pnorton   Peter  Norton
3  ladams    Lee    Adams

Group_membership table

Id  Group
1   Administrators
2   Developers
3   Technicians
```

Help is needed.
I have registered users in Mysql database users table.  These users can logon to the system with their username. From a different web page, I want to assign group membership to each  registered users by using PHP and MySQL. I do not know how I can achieve this.

```
Exemple;

Users        group_membership
pmartin  ->  Administrators, Developers
pnorton  ->  Technicians
ladams   ->  Developers, Technicians
```

Comment: Is their a field on your `users` table you want to store the 'role' in? Can they have multiple roles? If they can have multiple you want a userGroupMembership table or something that maps a 'user' id to a 'group membership' id.

Comment: Yes they have multiple roles

Answer (score 1):

Since, there is a many to many relationship here, create a new table to map user ids with membership id

```
user_membership
----------------
id              - PK
user_id         - foreign key referencing Users.id
membership_id   - foreign key referencing Group_membership.id
```

and use joins later to get the relevant details.

**Do not be tempted to store multiple values in one row as CSV. Normalization is your friend.**

Comment: @AdamonA Not here to write your code. Also, what do you mean? Insert a row from PHP? Create this "different web page? Ask specific questions and you will get answers. Maybe try and then ask again when you get stuck?

Comment: You did not answer my question. Thanks anyway